# Microsoft .Net Win Form Webview2 interop

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webview2, winforms-interop

I'm trying to interoperate with a page loaded in webview2. Basically what I'm trying to do is calling a win form method from the webview but the method **showMessageFromWebview2** is never fired.

The web content is loaded from localhost.

Any help would really be appreciated.

#### The code in win form

```cs
 async private void WebView_CoreWebView2Ready(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            testBrowser.CoreWebView2.WebMessageReceived += showMessageFromWebview2; 
        }

public void showMessageFromWebview2(Object sender, CoreWebView2WebMessageReceivedEventArgs args)
        {
            String msg = args.TryGetWebMessageAsString();
            MessageBox.Show(msg);
        }
```

#### Javascript code

```js
window.chrome.webview.postMessage(mJsonObject);
```

Comment: It should be fired, check IsWebMessageEnabled is true https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2settings.iswebmessageenabled?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1054.31#Microsoft_Web_WebView2_Core_CoreWebView2Settings_IsWebMessageEnabled

Comment: Also check your mJsonObject, what is it?

Comment: @demonplus it is just an object containing "messsage": "hello". But even if I put a string as param the win forms method is never fired.

Comment: @demonplus I have set it up when webview2 is ready: **testBrowser.CoreWebView2.Settings.IsWebMessageEnabled = true;**

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it! Thanks @demonplus!

I've just moved the **CoreWebView2.Settings** and the **WebMessageReceived** event handler to the initialization block just after the **EnsureCoreWebView2Async** method:

```cs
async private void InitializeAsync()
{
    await testBrowser.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(); // Wait for coreWebView2 initialization
    testBrowser.CoreWebView2.Settings.IsWebMessageEnabled = true;
    testBrowser.CoreWebView2.WebMessageReceived += showMessageFromWebview2;
}
```